# Getting last 6 months data from week column

Tags: sql-server, database, datetime

There is an int field say **WeekNum** and shows data like 202113, 202120.
And I want to get the for last 6 months.

If I subtract (weekid-26), then it will not give correct result.

Can there be a better way to get the result. Data in the current week can be anything like 202101 201952, etc.

DateAdd( month, -6) is not working here.

Sample data is:

```
WeekID
202110
202109
202108
202111
```

And the expected result is

```
WeekID:    
201936
201935
201934
201935
```

Comment: I would suggest adding sample data and expected results

Comment: Sample data is :

WeekID
202110
202109
202108
202111

And the expected result is

WeekID:

201936
201935
201934
201935

Answer (score 1):

**You should always store dates in `date` or `datetime` fields, otherwise you run into problems such as you have**

You need to divide by 100 to get the year, and modulo by 100 to get the week (unclear if it's `week` or `isoweek`)

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE DATEADD(week, WeekNum % 100, DATEFROMPARTS(WeekNum / 100, 1, 1)) >=
    DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())
```